# Rails: check_boxes submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails app I have a simple poll system. User checks options he likes and votes. The problem is check_boxes not showing and even if will showing I wouldn't Vote all the same because made some mistakes in my code likely

polls/show.html.haml:

```
- for question in @poll.questions.each
  %span= question.title
  %p= question.comment
  - form_tag upvote_question_path do
    %p= check_box_tag question, question.id
    %p= question.title
    = submit_tag 'Vote'
```

questions_controller.rb

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def upvote
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question.increment!(:votes_count)
    redirect_to :back
  end

end
```

If you need more information please comment!

Comment: where is this code written in view side(i.e which page)

- for question in @poll.questions.each
  %span= question.title
  %p= question.comment
  - form_tag upvote_question_path do
    %p= check_box_tag question, question.id
    %p= question.title
    = submit_tag 'Vote'

Comment: edited the path of view file

Answer (score 0):

```
Try  this

<% @poll.questions.each do |question| %>
  <span> <%= question.title %></span>
  <%= form_tag upvote_question_path do %>
     <p><%= check_box_tag :question_id, question.id %></p>
     <p><%= question.title %></p>
     <%= submit_tag 'Vote' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

In controller

 def upvote
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @question.increment!(:votes_count)
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. Your `update_vote_path` doesn't seem to be a member route?
2. You could easily achieve this with a button
3. You're looping through `questions` -- maybe this is empty?

---

**Code**

I would try this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :questions do
    #/questions/2/vote
    post :vote
end

#app/views/your_view
- for question in @poll.questions.each
  %span= question.title
  %p= question.comment
  - button_to "Vote", vote_questions_path(question), method: :post

#app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def vote
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @question.increment!(:votes_count)
    redirect_to :back
  end

end
```

---

**Modularity**

You're trying to manually submit a form with specific params, whereas you can handle all of that with the routes

I think your main issue will be how you're calling the `@poll.questions` variable. I don't believe it will be loading correctly, but without seeing your other code, this is just speculation